# Mongodb Liqbase script findOneAndUpdate for json type values

Tags: mongodb, liquibase

I have code that uses existing collection that I want to update name field value which is present in taskMap key how i run with run liqubase changeset for that .
**sample code :**
"changes": [
{
"collectionName": "bulk_import_job_spec"
},
{
"findOneAndUpdate": {
{"_id": 101},
[{"$set": {"task_map": {"import": {"_id": 1, "name": "Category Association"}}}}]
},
{
"returnNewDocument": true
}
]

Answer (score 0):

your questions is quite vague. Please provide some more details so that we can understand your issue.